# Using Auth::check() on different guards not working

Tags: laravel, authentication, middleware, guard

I have different guards

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'teacher' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'teachers',
    ],

    'doctor' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'doctors',
    ],
],
```

I have the same layout for all 3 users ( doctors, teachers and users ) I want to check on the view if they are signed in or not, if not I want to show a button sign in

I tried this:

```
@if(!auth()->guard('web')->check() || !auth()->guard('doctor')->check() || !auth()->guard('teacher')->check() )
                        <li><a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('getting-started') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a></li>
```

Pay attention when I only use: auth()::check() it refers to the default user whose guard is web

If I check only on one guard it works, but what about the others? Maybe my if statement is not correct, but anyway I want a solution for checking if any of the given users is signed in so I can hide the button and redirect him to his profile

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
@if(!(auth()->guard('web')->check() || auth()->guard('doctor')->check() || auth()->guard('teacher')->check() ))
   <li><a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('getting-started') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a></li>
```